# DATETIME Field value doesn't show in Lightning-Record-Edit-Form

Tags: apex, datetime, lightning-recordeditform, data-types

I have a problem with visability of Date/Time values in Lightning-record-edit-form.

This is my code:

```
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Event_Calendar__c" onsuccess={handleSuccessUpdate}>

              <lightning-input-field field-name="Title__c" value={selectedEvent.title} data-field="Title" type="text"></lightning-input-field>
              <lightning-input-field field-name="Start_Time__c" value={selectedEvent.start} data-field="start" type="date/time"></lightning-input-field>
              <lightning-input-field field-name="End_Time__c" value={selectedEvent.end} type="date/time"></lightning-input-field>
              <lightning-input-field field-name="Type__c" value={selectedEvent.type} data-field="Type" type="picklist" ></lightning-input-field>
                         
                <lightning-button label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick={createCancelUpdate} class="slds-m-right_small"></lightning-button>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" type="submit" label="Update Event" title="Update Event" onclick={handleSubmitUpdate}></lightning-button>
             
          </lightning-record-edit-form>
  </div>
```

and this is what I get: (Start Time and End Time values are missing)
[image]

[image]

Comment: What form are the `start` and `end` values in the `selectedEvent`? Can you [edit] to add example values being passed? Are they ISO date/time strings or something else?

Comment: I have edited the post

Comment: @Anyja, can you show what the value is in selectedEvent using the console? It should be in this format -  "2023-05-14T10:23:50.000Z"

Comment: Please see below:
 2023-05-23T12:34:00.000+0000 
 2023-05-18T12:24:00.000+0000 
 2023-06-02T19:37:00.000+0000